# Dynamically adding dropdownlists without data loss

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ok so I've been working on this for like... I don't know, 5 hours? I'm pulling my hair out starting to think it's just not possible with asp.net! ugh! I've looked at all kinds of resources (I even tried implementing DynamicControlsPlaceholder that was created by someone else years ago - which failed miserably). So here's the issue in hopes someone here has a solution!

I'm trying to have a page where the user can dynamically add DropDownLists without forgetting the values they set in the previous lists. So for example, let's say the user is given 1 DropDownList and chooses index 2. There will be a button below that says "Add" and that will add another DropDownList. When doing this, however, the page does a postback and the previous DropDownList loses the value of index 2 and resets back to index 0 instead. I can't figure out how to save the state of the DropDownList before the postback is made. The point of this is so that when the user is complete, they can click "Submit" with all the values made in the DropDownLists. Here's the code I currently have (that's important) which simply regenerates the same number of DropDownLists as there's supposed to be (based on the ViewState["layoutCount"]). Naturally, I should be able to "restore" the index that was selected before a reload of the page...

aspx file:

```
<table style="text-align:center; width:60%;">  
    <asp:Panel ID="layoutAreaPanel" runat="server" CssClass="paragraphStyle"  />
</table>
<asp:Button ID="cmdLayout1AddPage" runat="server" OnClick="cmdLayout1AddPage_Click" />
```

C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        CreatePanelInfo();
}
....
protected void CreatePanelInfo()
{
    int layoutCount = 0;

    if (ViewState["layoutCount"] != null)
        layoutCount = (int)(ViewState["layoutCount"]);

    for (int i = 0; i < layoutCount; i++)
    {
        TableRow mainRow = new TableRow();
        TableCell labelCell = new TableCell();
        TableCell dropDownListCell = new TableCell();

        Label cellLabel = new Label();
        cellLabel.Text = Language.GetLanguageText("ADDPAGE_PAGE", this.Page);
        cellLabel.CssClass = "paragraphStyle";

        labelCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
        labelCell.Controls.Add(cellLabel);

        DropDownList pnlDropDownList = new DropDownList();
        pnlDropDownList.ID = "pnlDropDownList" + (i + 1);
        pnlDropDownList.BorderWidth = 1;
        pnlDropDownList.Width = new Unit("100%");
        FillPageList(ref pnlDropDownList); //adds items to the list
        dropDownListCell.Controls.Add(pnlDropDownList);

        mainRow.Controls.Add(labelCell);
        mainRow.Controls.Add(dropDownListCell);
        layoutAreaPanel.Controls.Add(mainRow);
    }

    ViewState["layoutCount"] = layoutCount + 1;
}
....
protected void cmdLayout1AddPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreatePanelInfo();
}
```

Hopefully that's enough information to get a good answer... :S

Comment: Why the asp-classic tag? Edit: removed.

Comment: @Bond I think he just means `Web Forms`

Answer (score 0):

Only make your dropdown lists making a postback when their selected index changes.
In the code behind, store selections in Session variable.

```
public void AddDDL()
{
    var tmp = new DropDownList();
    tmp.SelectedIndexChanged += ddl_SelectedIndexChanged;
    Page.Controls.Add(tmp);
}

protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ddl = sender as DropDownList;
    var lists = Session["dropdownlists"] as Dictionary<DropDownList, int>;
    lists[ddl] = ddl.SelectedIndex;
}
```

and finally in postback event set the selected indices again:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostback)
    {
        var lists = Session["dropdownlists"] as Dictionary<DropDownList, int>;
        foreach (var item in lists)
           item.Key.SelectedIndex = item.Value;
    }
    else Session["dropdownlists"] = new Dictionary<DropDownList, int>();
}
```

Postback is not recommended because it is not user friendly. You should use an `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: Sorry, you should add `tmp.AutoPostback = true;` after making the object in method `AddDDL`